# WPF WebBrowser control does not show PDFs anymore (.NET5 Acrobat Reader ActiveX)

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, webbrowser-control, .net-5

I used the WebBrowser control to display PDFs. Therefore I installed the Acrobat Reader, so the InternetExplorer can display PDFs.

This solution was working for a long time. But suddenly it does not display PDF documents anymore. Other content like .html or .txt will still be displayed.

Displaying PDFs in the Internet explorer still works. So I assume that the ActiveX control from Adobe is installed correctly.

But using the WebBrowser, the screen stays gray for .pdf files.

Might be that I updated Visual Studio and Windows in the meantime.

Is AcrobatReader ActiveX control still working when using WPF WebBrowser control after lates Windows update?

On one of my computer I only "use" the software (no Visual Studio update lately). It was working before the last Windows Update.

---

Seems like I'm not the only one.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/439972/pdfs-stopped-working-win10.html

---

When setting the project explititly to x86 target platform, it works again.
With Any or x64 it doesn't show the PDFs.

But x86 is no solution for me, because I need a lot of memory and need x64.

Comment: Does one of the Solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993267/displaying-a-pdf-in-a-wpf-application-not-working-webbrowser-or-adobe-control solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, with Plug-In I ment the ActiveX control, so that is used by the InternetExplorer to display the Acrobat Reader inside the InternetExplorer