# Visual Studio WebBrowser Control does not show PDFs anymore

Tags: c#, pdf, webbrowser-control

I used the WebBrowser control to display PDFs in a Visual Studio C# Application.
This solution was working for a long time. But suddenly it does not display PDF documents anymore.
But using the WebBrowser, the screen stays gray for .pdf files.

When setting the project explititly to x86 target platform, it works again. With Any or x64 it doesn't show the PDFs, but x86 is no solution for me, because my application needs x64.

Here's a question extremely similar to mine, but there was no definitive answer to the problem.

[WPF WebBrowser control does not show PDFs anymore (.NET5 Acrobat Reader ActiveX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030502/wpf-webbrowser-control-does-not-show-pdfs-anymore-net5-acrobat-reader-activex)

Comment: Move to [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/), it doesn't need any plug-in to show PDF content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved in Windows Update.

"Internet Explorer 11 and applications that use the WebBrowser control may fail to open PDFs 64-bit versions of IE11 and applications that use the 64-bit version of the WebBrowser control may show PDFs as gray.

Resolved KB5004760"